# push projects to DevOps from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, devops

I am new to devops/git. I have a VS solution with 10 projects that I want to push into empty devops repo which I created. In VS > Options > Source control I have set it to Git. When I connected to Azure Devops from VS I had to specify a local repositiory. I initially set this to the Users directory. I then created Repositiory settings > .gitignore and commit/pushed it. The ignore file successfully uploaded into the repo and was pulled into the local repo. I can't see how to upload the projects. There seems to be no option to push them. I then changed the local repository to the directory where the solution projects are located. Now there is nothing available to pull or push.

I am the only developer on this project. My aim is to learn Devops not to create a team. In this case there is no existing repository to clone, which is the subject of almost all help articles. I'm trying to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

> I initially set this to the Users directory

Make sure to set it in the parent folder where your 10 projects reside.
That is where you can create a [new repo in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio).

> ### From an existing solution
>
> To create a repo from an existing solution not in version control, select the `Publish` button in the bottom-right of the lower status bar Visual Studio publish button.
> This creates a new Git repo in the same directory as your solution and opens up the Publish view in Team Explorer so you can push your code to Azure Repos or another remote Git repository.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/vspublish.gif?view=vsts]
And that is from where you can do a [git push from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pushing?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio).